# How to prove the Bijection of an Interval $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions

How can I prove that this image is bijective?

$$f: (-1,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad  x \longmapsto \frac{x}{1-x^2}
$$

is bijective without the use of the Steepness of the slope?

Answer (score 4):

This is a sketch of how; filling out details is left as an exercise.

$y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ implies $yx^2+x-y=0$, which has roots of product $-1$ so only one of them can be in $(-1,\,1)$. This proves $f$ never takes the same value twice.

Comment: What happens if $y=0$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg : I take it your question is rhetorical and your point is that this should have been mentioned.

Comment: @Michael Hardy There are else number of things that  should have been mentioned. I think my solution is much more better.

Comment: The reader is invited to decide whether they would rather regard $y=0$ as special or as a limit.

Answer (score 2):

If $0<x<1,$ then as the numerator $x$ increases, the positive denominator $1-x^2$ decreases, so the quotient as a whole grows. And the denominator approaches $0$ as the numerator approaches $1,$ so this goes up to $+\infty.$

If strictly increases then it's one-to-one, and if it's continuous and goes from $0$ up to $+\infty$ as as as its argument goes from $0$ to $1,$ then it's **onto** the interval $(0,+\infty).$

But the intermediate value theorem is needed for that.

You can do something similar for $-1<x<0,$ and the case $x=0$ is easy to understand, and the value of the function is negative for $-1<x<0$ and positive for $0<x<1,$ so that doesn't upset one-to-one-ness.

You can also do this with algebra, by solving a quadratic equation, provided you believe every nonnegative number has a nonnegative square root.

Comment: You need to say also that $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is a continuous function, otherwise your solution is total wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is a continuous function on $(-1,1)$,  $$\frac{x}{1-x^2}-\frac{y}{1-y^2}=\frac{(x-y)(1+xy)}{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)},$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^+}\frac{x}{1-x^2}=-\infty$$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}\frac{x}{1-x^2}=+\infty$$

Comment: @Michael Hardy By definition because $1-x^2>0$, $1-y^2>0$ and $1+xy>0$.

Comment: That is trivial, but that doesn't mean it's by definition. I would call something "by definition" only if there is a definition involved, and only if the proposition is immediate from the definition.

Comment: I proved that if $x\neq y$ then $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Also we see that $f$  it's onto.

Comment: I said that $f$ is a continuous function. It's enough.

Comment: Also, if so, $\frac{(x-y)(1+xy)}{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}$ can be negative, which says that you don't exactly understand about what you say. Bye.